Taking an int from shared memory
In my current project, I have to work with a zone of shared memory of 100 bytes, plus an integer right after it, so, around 108, I think.
However, I can't seem to isolate this int.
I don't have much idea of how this works, so I'm really sorry if it looks like I am not trying.
What I did is, I tried to cast the the supposed start of the integer into a integer pointer, just like this:
int *number=(int *) data[100]
Data being the pointer to the shared memory after a shmat.
The initialization of the shared memory is as follows (excluding error checking, in order not to add many lines of code here):
shmid=shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 100+sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0600)
Is there a way to do what I am describing?
Edit: True, much better  to just upload the code:
char *data;
int shmid;
if ((shmid=shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 100+sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0600)) == -1){
            printf("Error shmget");
            exit(3);
    }
int *number = (int *)data[100];


To begin with, (int *) data[100] makes no sense. You probably want (int *) &data[100]. And if data is a pointer to an int, or an array of int, then the cast isn't needed. Please try to create a [mre] to show us. Seeing actual code is much better than reading a vague description of it.

I think that is enough as a minimal reproducible example? It reflects all the problem, I think.

A [mre] is a reproducible example. That means it provides a complete program that other people can compile and execute to reproduce the problem. It does not need to be your complete program; you should reduce it to just the parts needed to reproduce the problem, but it should be a whole program. That said, the code shown never assigns a value to data, so there is no reason data[100] would provide the desired address.

You forgot the call to shmat: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmat.2.html So, your data points nowhere. After that int *number = (int *)&data[100]; will get you a pointer to the int at the end.

If offset 100 (from a page boundary) is a multiple of _Alignof(int) (which it probably is if sizeof(int) <= 4), then (int *)&data[100] or (int *)(data + 100) will be valid pointers to an int. Otherwise, you would need to use memcpy(&num, data + 100, sizeof(int)); where num is declared as int num; to copy the value out of the buffer, or memcpy(data + 100, &num, sizeof(int)); to copy the value into the buffer.

int *number=(int *)ptr;

If you dereference the  number pointer you may invoke undefined behaviour.
use memcpy instead.
int number;
memcpy(&number, ptr, sizeof(number));

